# How to change deafult behaviour cleander date using custom js in magento 2 Product edit page at backend

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, jquery, custom-attributes, requirejs

I have created custom attribute for Product as date and time and want to disable past dates?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**While loading page Default Datepicker or calender object will get created so even if you try to change the behavior of Datepicker or calender it won't work reflect.
There is one solution but it will be not good practice.
First Destroy Default object then create an object of Datepicker or calender like:**

```
 $("input[name='product[go_live_date_time]']").datepicker('destroy');

 $("input[name='product[go_live_date_time]']").datetimepicker({
          showTime: true,
          showOn: "button",
          hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
          buttonText: "",
          minDate: 0,
          stepHour: 1,
          stepMinute: 5,

      });
```

Comment: Worked like charm for me ! Thanks Pramod for the quick solution !!